# Termcal Two week cycle

Tags: termcal

One of my classes is given a list of what is coming up on a two week cycle; our timetable works this way.  I've been trying to adapt some other examples I've found using termcal.  This is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{termcal}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\patchcmd{\endcalendar}{[l]}{[c]}{}{}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\newcommand{\TRClass}{
\calday{Monday}
\skipday
\calday{Wednesday}
\calday{Thursday}
\calday{Friday}
\skipday\skipday
\calday{Tuesday}
\calday{Wednesday}
\calday{Thursday}
\calday{Friday}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{calendar}{08/19/2019}{2}
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{0.65in}
\TRClass
\caltexton{1}{}
\end{calendar}
\end{document}
```

The formatting is off (overprinted).  Is anyone able to suggest what is going wrong?
This is my first practice with this package.
Thanks

Comment: Could you attach a picture (maybe drawn by hand) of what you want to draw?

Comment: You have confused the optional argument with the mandatory argument. It should look like this: `\calday[Monday]{\classday}`